# Is $x=0$ a local minimum of $f(x)=x^{2/3}(5-x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions, curves, wolfram-alpha

It seems to be decreasing for values below zero and increasing for values between zero and 2.

However $f'(0) = \frac{(-5 (x-2))}{3 x^{1/3}}|_{x=0}$ does not exist.

So it's not a local minimum?

Btw, why does [WA seem to say that $x=0$ is not a loc min](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E(2%2F3)(5-x))?

[image]

It's not decreasing for values below zero?

Comment: The problem here is that you have not defined the domain of your function. For negative values of $x$, I would say that $x^{2/3} = |x|^{2/3}$: in such a case, both on the left and on the right of $0$  $f$ is strictly positive, while $f(0)=0$, so we have a local minimum.

Comment: @Crostul: Isn't $x^{2/3}$ perfectly well-defined for negative $x$? Squaring, and taking the (real) cube root, applied in either order, produce the same result. So there is no need at all to use absolute value here. If you are worried about the two nonreal cube roots, then I would say you should have the same worry when $x$ is positive (including the case of using $|x|$ in lieu of $x$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you made a minor error in taking the derivative. Nonetheless, critical points are points in the domain of $f$ where $f'$ either is zero or fails to exist. So $x=0$ is an ordinary critical point, and a sign analysis for $f'$ shows that a local minimum does indeed occur there. (Determine the signs of the factors of $f'$ and combine them to get the sign of $f'$; signs of factors can change only where they are zero or undefined.)

Incidentally, one shouldn't say "$x=0$ is a local minimum for $f$". $x$ isn't the minimum value, it is the point at which the minimum occurs. The (local) minimum value itself is $f(0)$, which also happens to be $0$.

Comment: Okay thanks MPW ^-^ I'm gonna wait awhile to see if there are any dissenters.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1699990/140308) says $x=0$ is not a local minimum. May I please get your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: That answer is incorrect. I have commented to that effect on that answer. (And again, it isn't the value of $x$, but rather the value of $f(x)$, that would be or not be the local minimum value.)

Comment: *(0,f(0)) is not a local minimum. Thanks ^-^

Comment: I would even say that isn't quite right. One speaks of a "minimum value of $f$", meaning that it is a number of the form $f(x)$ for some $x$. It is a point in the image of $f$ (a "$y$-value"), not a point in the domain (an "$x$-value") or a point on the graph (an "$(x,y)$-value"). I don't mean to nitpick about this, but the terminology is rather specific. So I am claiming that $f(0)$ (which is the number $0$) is indeed a local minimum value of $f$. The other answer you mention claims that it is not, and I say that is wrong.

Comment: Ah well, I guess so. Thanks ^-^

Answer (score 1):

Near $x=0$, $f(x) \sim 5 x^{2/3}$. Hence $f(0)=0$ and $f(x) \geq 0$ in a neighborhood of $x=0$. This means that $x=0$ is a local minimum.

I would like to remark that $x^{2/3}=\sqrt[3]{x^2}=\left( \sqrt[3]{x} \right)^2$, and therefore it can be computed on the whole real axis. Wolfram Alpha probably assumes that $$x^{2/3} = \exp \left( \frac23 \log x \right),$$ but this representation is valid for $x >0$ only.

The fact that the derivative does not exist is not an abstruction: think of $x \mapsto |x|$. If you are thinking of the Fermat Theorem, it precisely states that if a function attains a local minimum (or maximum) at $x_0$ *and* the function is differentiable at $x_0$, then the derivative at $x_0$ vanishes. In your case, the function is *not* differentiable at the minimum point, so that the theorem does not apply.

Comment: Okay thanks Siminore ^-^ I'm gonna wait awhile to see if there are any dissenters.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1699990/140308) says $x=0$ is not a local minimum. May I please get your thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 1):

The given function $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, let alone twice differentiable. As a consequence the usual test for a local minimum cannot be applied here. But we can argue as follows:

Since $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for $0<|x|<1$ we have a local minimum at $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks Christian Blatter. [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1699990/140308) says $x=0$ is not a local minimum. May I please get your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: @BCLC: The linked answer has been discredited. – Se my edit.

Comment: Ah thanks. $f(x) = \frac{1}{|x|}$ is not a counterexample because $f(0)$ is undefined?

Answer (score -1):

$$f(x) = x^{2/3}(5 - x)$$

The derivative is

$$f'(x) = x^{2/3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\frac{(5-x)}{x} - 1\right)$$

If we set $f'(x) = 0$ we find two solutions: $x = 0$ which is excluded because it makes the function to explode, and $x = 2$. Indeed if you substitute $x = 2$ you find

$$f'(2) = 2^{2/3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{2} - 1\right) = 0$$

So $x = 2$ is a candidate for being a max or a min. To establish what it is, we study the second derivative. Easy algebra gives

$$f''(x) = -\frac{2}{9}(5-x) x^{-4/3} - \frac{4}{3}x^{-1/3}$$

so

$$f''(2) = -1.32283$$

So we get that $x= 2$ is a \textbf{maximum} point for that function.

Also you can see it in your plot!

Instead, $x = 0$ is not a minimum because the plot doesn't change its curvature. You have like a "bristly jump" as you can see in your plot: the function is not changing from "going upside" to "going downside" or vice versa.

Comment: I do not agree with your answer, when you talk about the origin. There is no jump at $x=0$, and that point is indeed a local minimum.

Comment: It cannot be a local minimum! Minima and maxima are points in which the curve of the function changes its behavior, namely if it was increasing, then after a maximum it will decrease, and vice versa if it was decreasing, after a minimum it will increase. In $x = 0$ there is no variation of the increase or decrease of that function, indeed the function keep increasing.. so it's not a minimum. I didn't mean a real jump, but if you look, the function keep increasing with a sort of sudden sharp curvature.. But tell me more, maybe I'm completely wrong?

Comment: @1over137 am I wrong? I think the function is decreasing for $x<0$

Comment: You are simply wrong about the behavior at $x=0$. The function does not "explode" there. It has a cusp there, but it still has a local minimum there as well. It isn't differentiable there, but so what? It is the derivative, not the function itself, that "explodes" there. $$$$ Failure for the derivative to exist at a point of the domain is one of the criteria for a critical point -- not just that the derivative exists and is zero.

Comment: @MPW Interesting. As far as I know: If f not differentiable at $x=0$, then f is not differentiable. Hence $f'(x)$ does not exist. Assuming all that is right, how can we say $(0,f(0))$ is a local minimum? I initially said that $f'(x) < 0$ for $x < 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for $x \in (0,2)$. However to say $f'(x)$ is nonsensical because $f'(x)$ does not exist?

Comment: @MPW Yes sorry its the derivative. But I don't really think it's a local minimum, otherwise Fermat Theorem will turn to be useless.

Comment: Differentiability is a nice tool to use when looking for local extrema -- if the function happens to be differentiable. If it does not, then differentiability has nothing to do with local extrema. It certainly isn't required.

Comment: @MPW I wasn't tagged and so was not notified. Anyway, how can we speak about $f'(x)$ if it does not exist? (Too basic a question?)

Comment: @BCLC: It is allowed to have the domain of $f'$ be a proper subset of the domain of $f$. In other words, a function can have a derivative that isn't defined everywhere the function is defined--the function is then said to be differentiable wherever the derivative exists. For example, $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ is differentiable except at $x=0$.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks XD @MPW